# Simple Inverse Regex

Tags: regex

This one should be simple.

I want to match any numbers that do NOT have a series of numbers in the front.

I have the regex, but it does the exact opposite. I need an inverse of it.

Examples:

```
123456 - NOT MATCH
456789 - MATCH
451236 - MATCH
```

Right now, it's the opposite of the above.

The regex: `^(123)`

Comment: Usually you can just pass an "invert results" option to the regex engine.

Comment: Right, in grep for example is `-v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?!^123)\d+
```

`^` starts in the beginning of the line

`(?!^123)` not starts with 123

`\d+` and then all the the digits you can get

Note that this only covers integers. You can change de last option to search other desired formats, like `.5`, `-13.5`, `2.6e+10` etc, etc...